# Serializing BitmapImage in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, bitmapimage

I'm trying to serialize a custom class, however I get a error saying System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage is not marked as serializable. I understand that I will need to convert it a byte array or something in order to serialize it, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

I've found this question: [Serializing a WPF Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205698/serializing-a-wpf-image) but don't know how to adapt it for my use. Could someone point me in the right direction and possibly link some material to read up on when dealing with serialization in WPF.

Comment: The question you linked to seems to cover exactly what you are asking for. You should post some of your code so its easier to see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to pass the ImageSource to the constructor of the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) and then use the Pixels property of the WriteableBitmap to get to the pixel data.

Comment: How would this help me with serializing my images? Could you elaborate/provide an example?

Comment: The pixels property is a byte array. Byte arrays can be serialized. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you wish to encode the image as a JPG, PNG,... or are you trying to simply store/transport the colors?